# $ \int_{0}^{88} \sin \sqrt{x} $ dx, $n=4$ . Use the Midpoint Rule with the given value of $n$ to approximate the integral.

Tags: calculus

$ \int_{0}^{88} sin \sqrt{x} $ dx, $n=4$ . My endpoints are $0$, $22$, $44$, $66$, $88$ and the midpoints are $11$, $33$ ,$55$ , and $77$. I am do not know how to calculate after this point

[image]

Comment: Calculate $\frac{88}{4}\left(\sin(\sqrt{11})+\cdots+\sin(\sqrt{77})\right)$. Now it is just calculator work. The usual default assumption in calculus is that we are using radian notation, but the author could be intending degrees.  Maybe you could get clarification.

Comment: my answer is 9.6707. I rounded to 4 decimal places and got 9.671; however, the computer program I am using says my answer is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: The default assumption, as I mentioned, is that we are using radians. So put your calculator in **radian mode**. Then for example $\sin(\sqrt{11})\approx -0.1741398$. (I checked, in degree mode we get what you mentioned.)  By the way, it is quite weird to use $n=4$ with such a large interval.  Was your problem stated exactly as you put it, or did the $88$ come from you?

Comment: Do they specify what rounding? Note that $9.671$ is not $9.6707$ rounded to $4$ decimal places, you have rounded to $3$ decimal places.

Comment: Is the answer 18.12003021 if I round 4 decimal places is the answer 18.1200?

Comment: No, the rounding makes little difference. Did you try radians?

Comment: Yes it is in radians. Am I counting decimal places to the right of the decimal?

Comment: Yes, for radians I get $18.12003$, to $4$ decimal places $18.1200$, to $4$ **significant figures** $18.12$.

Comment: Yeah that worked. So whenever I have a mid point question I should keep the b-a/4 in fraction form and multiply the entire (quantity) by it?

Comment: Well, you could multiply each term by $\frac{b-a}{n}$, and add up. It is a bit less work if you multiply by $\frac{b-a}{n}$ at the end. Whether fraction form or decimal form does not matter much, as long as you keep full calculator accuracy and do not round the terms before adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default assumption in calculus is that angles, unless otherwise specified, are measured in radians. If that is the case, put your calculator in **radian mode** amd calculate 
$$\frac{88}{4}\left(\sin(\sqrt{11})+\sin(\sqrt{33})+\sin(\sqrt{55})+\sin(\sqrt{77})\right).$$
To $5$ decimal places, I get $18.12003$. Rounded to say $4$ decimal places this is $18.1200$.

**Remark:** Weird problem, particularly using the default assumption that we are using radians. With $n=4$, one cannot expect a numerical method such as Trapezoidal Rule, Midpoint Rule, or Simpson's Rule, to produce even a crude estimate of the integral.

Comment: You are welcome. Automated graders interfere with the learning of mathematics, since they look only at answers, and do not distinguish between an essentially correct solution with a minor numerical glitch, and a conceptually wrong solution.